# How can I copy more than one page of text with Adobe PDF reader?

Tags: pdf-reader

I have this PDF document opened in my Adobe PDF reader, and if I press `<CTRL><A>`, `<CTRL><C>` and `<CTRL><V>`, only one page of text is copied.

What's wrong? Is this some licence or permission subject? How can I copy the full text with `<CTRL><A>` and `<CTRL><C>`?

Answer (score 2):

In Adobe PDF reader, `<CTRL><A>` and `<CTRL><C>` work differently depending on the current page view mode.

In the reader, navigate to View >> Page Display and choose "Enable Scrolling". Then, `<CTRL><A>` will select the whole PDF. As long as the Page Display is "Single Page View", `<CTRL><A>` will only copy one page.